# Loops, trouble understanding loops please help a beginner

Tags: java

```
int a= IO.readInt();
int b = IO.readInt();
int z = 0; 
int i;
for(i =0; z<=b; i++) {
  z=z+a;
} 

System.out.println(i);
```

a.) what is the actual output of the code, given the following input? 
input: a reads in 20, b reads in 75.

b). what mathematical operation does this code resemble.

c. As implemented does this code correctly accomplish the operation you identified in (b)? if so provide some test cases to show this. if not, fix the bug in the code. ``

Ok so my professor went over what the  answers where and I want to know if any of you guys can explain what is actually happening in this code. What i got for  a.) was 4 but don't understand how it is 4. and for mathematical operation does the code resemble i got += addition and that was no where close to the answer. I need a better understanding on loops, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to get some information regarding the for loop? Or loops in general? A good starting point would be [Java Docs: The for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Hi Robert, would you mind editing your question to tell us what your reasoning is and how you would answer each question?  Generally we don't like to do others' homework, but I'm sure you could get clarifying feedback on what you might be doing wrong.  If you're totally stumped, try thinking through how this function might change over time.  What is the flow from time zero to the end of the program?  Write down how each variable changes, i.e. what are their values at each iteration of the loop?  How about when the test (`z<=b`) is made?

Comment: Well if the answer for `b` were `addition` shouldn't the ouput be `95` instead of `4`?

Comment: This isn't homework this was a question i have had on on an exam and wanted some clarification on for loops.

Answer (score 0):

The output is how many times the loop continued until z > b.  Do a simple addition to z + a each time through and you should understand how it's executed

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the best explanation I can give for for loops, and what is happening inside your code.

First off, for loops have 3 parts to them, the `initializer`, the `expression`, and the `incrementor`, like so:

```
for (initializer; expression; incrementor)
```

Your initializer initializes your int `i` to 0. It does it as long as z is less than or equal to b (`z <= b`), and each time it does it it increments `i` by 1;

You loop adds the first input to `z`, until it is no longer lower than `b`. The first time you run it, it adds 20 to `z`, and 1 to `i`. It then comes back to the beginning of the loop, and checks the expression.

Because `z` is still less than 75, it runs again. This makes `z` = 40, and `i` = 2. Again, `z` is less than 75, so it runs *again*. This time, `z` is 60, and `i` is 3; But 60 is still less then 75.

I guess you can see where this is going. This brings us to the final iteration. It adds another 20 to `z`, and another 1 to `i`. Now `z` = 80, and `i` = 4. And it checks the expression of the loop for the last time. Because `z` is greater than 75, the loop terminates. This leaves `i` with a value of 4, which is what your are getting as output

Comment: So does a for loop run infinite times until it gets to 4?

Comment: No, it runs until the expression returns false, in this case, when `z` is greater than `75`. If `b` was changed to `95` instead, and `a` was left the same, `i` would be `5`

Answer (score 0):

First I will explain how a for-loop works and then I will answer your questions:

```
for(initialization of variables; condition-testing; increment variables) {
  statements;
}
```

The **initialization of variables** is where often you initialize a counter. In your case variable i is set to 0, `i =0`.

In the **condition-testing** you test whether a condition is true and if it's true the code within the for loop is being executed. In your case the condition is: **z<=z+a**. If this doesn't hold you don't execute the code within your for-loop and skip to right after the for-loop, which is in your case `System.out.println(i)`

Lastly **after**, AFTER! one iteration the `increment variables` part is updated. What I mean by one iteration is when the body of the for-loop is executed from from beginning to end. In your case this is `z=z+a`.  I can't stress enough that the increment happens AFTER one iteration. In your case `i++` is executed which means that the variable i is incremented by one. i++ is the same as i = i + 1. The old value of i + 1.

Now to answer your questions. 
a) I will explain what happens step by step and mark the final answer in bold.

1. i is initialized with 0, `i=0`.
2. `z<=b` is tested for the first time, right now z=0 and b=75 so the condition `z<=b` holds and because of that the statements within the for loop are being executed..
3. `z=z+a` is being executed. The right side of the equals sign `=` is always evaluated first and then assigned to the left side of the `=` sign. In other words: `z=z+a` will look like this  `z = 0 + 20` and the new value for `z = 20`
4. This was the first iteration, now finally `i` is incremented. `i++` the value of `i` is now `1`. `i = 1`
5. `z<=b` is tested for the second time, `z = 20` as we saw in step 3 and b=75 so the condition `20<=75` is true and the statement(s) within the for-loop are executed.
6. `z=z+a`, z = 20+20, the new value for z becomes 40. `z = 40`
7. This was the second iteration, i is once again incremented by one `i++`, `i` is now `2`. `i = 2`
8. `z<=b` is evaluated for the third time. z=40 and b=75, so the condition is true and the loop is being executed.
9. z=z+a, z=40+20, the new value for z becomes 60. `z = 60`
10. i is incremented by 1. i becomes 3. `i = 3`
11. z<=b is tested for the 4th time, z=60 and b=75, so the condition is true and the statements within the for loop are executed.
12. z=z+a, z=60+20, the new value for z becomes 80. `z = 80`
13. i++ is incremented, i becomes 4. `i = 4`
14. z<=b is tested for the 5th time, z=80 and b=75, this time z is no longer smaller or equal to b. 80 is not equal or smaller than 75. So the statements in the for-loop are not executed this time. And since the increment of i only happens AFTER that the last statement in the body is successfully executed, i remains at 4.

The code resumes after the for-loop, so now `System.out.println(i)` is being executed. This prints the value of i, as you can see the value of i was incremented to the value of 4 in the loop. That's the value that gets printed. **4**

b/c) I don't fully get what is meant by mathematical operation, but the code does the same as: rounding up 75/20.

To get a good understanding of a for-loop you can maybe look at this simplified example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
 System.out.println(i);
}
```

You will see that the output of this program will be:

```
1
2
```

This is because it starts at zero and stops when the condition i<2 is no longer true. As a handy trick you can just remember that the number here i<**number** should be the number of iterations in the for loop. (If i is also initialized at 0 and incremented by 1, which you will see often).

Comment: So I is only being printed when Z<=b, and my question is how is the mathematical expression be divisor operation. I don't fully understand the operation that is occurring at this point, i understand that I is being incremented everytime it is true, i see so When I is incremented the value of Z is increasing by 20.